# Pointers on PIC32 device not matching expected values in the debugger

Tags: c, pointers, mplab

Quick question here regarding the behavior of pointers (I'm working on a project on a PIC32MX270F256D).

I have the following code currently implemented:

```
void main(void)
{
    int size = 15;
    int check;
    int *ptr;

    ptr = &size;
    check = *ptr;

    while(1);        //just so it hangs at the end
}
```

Now I am stepping through the program with variable watches on.  After the declaration of size, I can see in the watch window that size has a value 15, and is at address 0xA000FFC8 (so far so good).  After the line `ptr = &size;`, the watch window shows that ptr has value 0xA000FFC8 (as expected).  Now after the final line (`check = *ptr;`), the watch window says check has the value 0xA000FFC8.

This seems to me like very simple functionality.  At the end, while hanging in the while loop, check should have the value 15, no?  If yes, is my code incorrect, or is there apparently something wrong with the Microchip IDE?  If not, what am I missing to make this work like it should?

Thanks.

-Sean

Note:  I'm using MPLAB X and the Microchip's XC32 compiler.

Comment: What if your compiler determined that your code doesn't actually do anything, so it didn't bother generating some code (i.e., optimized it)?  Does `check` get 15 if you change `int *ptr;` to `volatile int *ptr;`?  Can you turn off compiler optimizations?

Comment: ^+1. Looks like optimization issues.

Comment: this line: check = *ptr; results in undefined behaviour because dereferencing a point to address 15 (where address 15 is NOT an allocated memory address) means the read of the contents of memory may/probably is into a readonly memory page.  this 'may' result in a seg fault event.

Comment: in the end, the check variable will have the value from memory where ptr points (in this case, address 15) the actual value could be anything

Comment: @user3629249 This is not true. `ptr` has a value of `size`'s address, so dereferencing it will give the value of `size`.

Comment: @indiv,
It was definitely an optimization issue.  Changed int *ptr to volatile int *ptr as per your suggestions and all works as expected.  Indiv, if you want to answer, feel free.  I will check back in a few days, and if no one has answered I will answer myself.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an optimization issue.  Your compiler determined that your code doesn't actually do anything, so it didn't bother generating the code.  Specifically, your code doesn't actually use the value you store in `check`.

You can declare your pointer as `volatile` to force the compiler not to optimize it away.  I.e., `int *ptr;` becomes `volatile int *ptr;`.

You could also use the value of `check` in a meaningful way, like by printing it out.

```
printf("My pointer %p points to %u.\n", ptr, check);
```

Or you can look in your compiler documentation and figure out how to turn off optimizations.  When debugging, it is often helpful to compile without optimizations so that the compiled code closely matches your source code.

Note:  You will at some point want to access hardware or chip registers that have been mapped to memory addresses.  When you do this, make sure these pointers to mapped memory are volatile or you will have the same problem!

Comment: Just to clarify, declaring "volatile int *ptr;" solved my problem.  I never bothered trying to turn optimizations off.